# Django / Model with ManytoManyField gives en entry by default

Tags: django

Models.py

```
class Scenes(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField('Scene name', max_length=60,unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    fileGltf = models.FileField(null=TRUE, blank=False, upload_to="3dfiles/")
    
    record_date = models.DateTimeField('Scene date')

    manager = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  
    prev = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', 
        related_name='previous',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    next = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
         blank=True, )
```

Views.py (extract)

```
    if form.is_valid():
        nextSceneSlug=form.cleaned_data.get('name')
        scenes=form.save(commit=False)
        scenes.manager = request.user
        scenes.record_date = now
        scenes.prev = ScenePrevious
        form.save()
```

When I record a new entry with the models.py, there is a default value for this next field/
(World is the scene origine) But when I add it with the admin panel, there is not.
How can I do it in my views.py so it leaves a blank field ?

[image]

Comment: The modeling looks quite strange, shouldn't the `next` of *A* be *B* if *B* is the `prev` of *A*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no sense to specify a `prev` and `next` if it means that if *A* is the `prev` of *B*, then *B* is a member of the `next` of *A*. You can define a simple `ForeignKey`:

```
class Scene(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField('Scene name', max_length=60, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    file_gltf = models.FileField(null=TRUE, upload_to='3dfiles/')
    record_date = models.DateTimeField('Scene date')
    manager = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    previous = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', 
        related_name='next',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
```

If you thus have for example scenes *B* and *C* that both have *A* as `previous`, then `A.next.all()` will return a `QuerySet` that contains *B* and *C*.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Scene` instead of <s>`Scenes`</s>.

Comment: The fact is A may have multiple B, but B will only have one A.  In this case ForeignKey is the right choice ?

Comment: @fransua: yes a `ForeignKey` is a many-to-one field, so a `Scene` has (at most) one `previous`, and can have multiple `Scene`s that see that object as previous (thus can have multiple `next` ones).

Comment: I got it. But how can I select all the next one of A ? For performance issue I thought it would be better to have a specific field.

Comment: @fransua: if you have a `Scene` object `myscene` you can use `myscene.next.all()`.